# Child components update each other?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a navigation bar of sorts using react. What I currently have is a `Navbar` which is a parent component of `NavbarElement` components. The issue I am having, is that when a NavbarElement is clicked, it attains a color indicating that you are on that page. However, I can't seem to find a way to erase that state once it is clicked, as a different NavbarElement is clicked which has no relation to the clicked NavbarElement. Is there a way to update that other NavbarElement from a different one? How would I best get around this?

This is what I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Navbar.scss";


export interface Link {
  link: string,
  text: string
}
interface NavbarElementProps{
  index: number,
  link: Link,
  highlightColor: string,
  setNavbarCurrentIndex: (index: number) => void
}

interface NavbarElementState {
  highlighted: boolean
}

export interface NavbarProps {
  links: Link[],
  currentHighlight: string,
  currentLink: string
}

interface NavbarState {
  currentLinkIndex: number
}


class NavbarElement extends React.Component<NavbarElementProps, NavbarElementState>{
  constructor(props: NavbarElementProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { highlighted: this.props.index===0 };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="NavbarElement">
        <li style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.highlighted ? this.props.highlightColor : "inherit" }}>
          <a href={this.props.link.link}
            target="_blank"
            onClick={()=>{
              this.props.setNavbarCurrentIndex(this.props.index);
              this.setState({highlighted: true});
            }}>
            {this.props.link.text}
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export class Navbar extends React.Component<NavbarProps, NavbarState>{

  private setCurrentIndex = (index: number) => this.setState({ currentLinkIndex: index });
  constructor(props: NavbarProps) {
    super(props);
    let validCurrent = props.links.findIndex(link => link.link === props.currentLink);
    if (validCurrent === undefined) {
      throw new RangeError(`Invalid input-current link MUST be one of the other links inputted.
      The current link ${this.props.currentLink} is not one of the links.`);
    }
    this.state = { currentLinkIndex: validCurrent };
  }

  private calculateNavbarElements(): JSX.Element[] {
    return this.props.links.map((link: Link, index: number) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <NavbarElement
            index={index}
            link={link}
            highlightColor={this.props.currentHighlight}
            setNavbarCurrentIndex={this.setCurrentIndex}
          />
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Navbar">
        <ul>
          {this.calculateNavbarElements()};
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

In the `onClick` within the `render` method of NavbarElement, I set the component itself to be highlighted, which works. Right now, any link clicked just attains the highlight color. However, I am lost as to how to un-highlight the component that was previously highlighted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT: Thank you those in the comments!** I passed in highlight as a prop and everything is awesome, thanks!

Comment: The one which is selected should be tracked in the parent, `Navbar`. Then whether it's highlighted or not should be passed down as a prop. You can track which one is highlighted by index, though that's not ideal. It's better if you can use an ID of some kind when tracking which one is stored.

Comment: What about checking both highlighted and currentindex for you li element in NavbarElement?

Comment: I agree with @Jayce444 , you should move your [state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and let the parent navbar handle it. Another way would be to use routes and show the different colors in dependance of the current route.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you those in the comments. Making `highlight` a prop worked great.